# User management plugin/framework for Grails?

Tags: security, grails, plugins

Is there a user-management plugin for grails?

Nearly every website requires things like:

- Users  Login/Authentication
- Registration (w/ email verification)
- Forgotten email reminders  User
- User Profiles

Are there any Grails plugins/frameworks/whatever that provide things like this as a base to build upon?

I know how to build these things, so I'm not looking for that type of answer.  It just seems silly for every person out there to re-implement this type of basic functionality.

A similar example in Java would be AppFuse, but that is far more involved than what I'm looking for here.

Comment: Any one reading this as of 2014 should definitely give a look to nimble plugin http://grails.org/plugin/nimble

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Anyone looking at this question today in 2010 would do well to look at the Nimble plugin: http://www.grails.org/plugin/nimble

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for at the time, wish I had it then.  Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

There are a couple I know of,

http://www.grails.org/AcegiSecurity+Plugin

based on the popular Acegi Security (now called Spring Security), possibly a little heavyweight for what you want.

and secondly

http://www.grails.org/Authentication+Plugin

which is a far lighter weight implementation.

Others can be found at http://www.grails.org/Plugins, under 'Security Plugins'

Comment: I've used Spring Security lots in the past, it's one part that I would likely use to build something like I was requesting.

I has assumed the authentication plugin was nearly identical, but after looking at it again, maybe that is what I want.  I'll need to investigate.

Answer (score 6):

Here are a few new additions: [Spring Security UI](http://grails.org/plugin/spring-security-ui) and [Grum](http://code.google.com/p/grum/). Both have recent (2012) activity unlike Stark and Nimble which seem to have stopped development (last updates were from 2 years ago).

Comment: Nimble is very well maintained

Comment: I stand corrected. It seems development only slowed down for 2011-2012 but started to pick up again around July 2013 for Nimble. Thanks sudhir for the information.

Comment: Yeah, I am the author/maintainer of the plugin :) And its going to be well managed now on

Answer (score 5):

If you're interested in a Spring-security based solution you could look at Stark:

http://www.grails.org/Stark+Security+Plugin